# GPower: unequal number of measurements?

Tags: anova, statistical-power, gpower

I'm in psych research, so typically I have my subjects do ~40 trials per condition. If I have an uneven number of trials per condition (say, 30 in one and 40 in another) and a 2 x 2 within-subjects ANOVA, how would this impact the output on a power analysis (e.g. G Power)?

After cleaning my data the output is: each row is 1 participant and each column is their average across those trials for 1 condition (so 2 x 2 ANOVA = 4 conditions).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this really helps you, but you cannot consider the number of trials per person in a power analysis in GPower. If you want to examine the effect of number of trials in power, you have to switch to a mixed model analysis as deteiled, e.g. in this [paper](https://www.journalofcognition.org/articles/10.5334/joc.10/).

Best,
Stefan

Comment: Thanks - so for a 2 x 2 within-subjects ANOVA (4 groups) the input into G Power would need to be "# of groups = 1, # of measurements = 4"? In my original question I'm just trying to figure out whether the uneven # of trials weakens power for ANOVA, do you know if this is the case?

Comment: You can't power this with gpower. You can make some simplifying assumptions that allow you to use gpower as a starting point.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Would you mind expanding on what you mean?

Comment: There are a few ways to analyze this. The best way is to use all of the data. If you have 50 subjects, and each does 40 trials, in one sense your sample size is 2000, in another sense it's 50. You can treat this as a cluster randomized trial,  In another sense it's 50. The effective sample size is somewhere in between. See, for example: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4521133/

Comment: You could also just ignore the number of trials per person and calculate the average per person. Then you can use gpower, but you'll lose power. Is this something you want to publish?